# Training Set in Python sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

If I have a biased dataset in terms of subgroup sizes for example if I'm trying to predict 'a','b','c' labels but my dataset has 1000 'a' labels, 500 'b' labels and 250 'c' labels, does sklearn have any workaround to this or does it automatically take this into account?

Comment: You may be interested to this project https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn provides the funtionality to deal with imbalanced data itself, you have to check out with the different metrics avalaible [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values) and use it to find the best metric for which your model have higher accuracy rates. Scroing metrics is the parameter which can help you with imbalanced datasets. Just choose your scoring while training the model according to your problem and it will considerably help to deal it with.

> When dealing with imbalanced data you can always do oversampling for
>   the classes. This process can be done in data preprocessing.

More about dealing with imbalanced data you can read [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values) and [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn)